# How do I limit/filter the output to the pipeline in powershell?

Tags: powershell, shell, terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh

1..100 | foreach {
    $response= invoke-restmethod www.azuredevops.com/api/v2/somequery
    Write-Output "string showing the status of CI pipeline"  # i don't want this to go into pipe
    cls
}
Write-Output "formated string which contains Build details in json format which will  be outputted to the pipeline"
```

Above script will be run in both windows-powershell and linux-powershell. In this script I'll be printing both "**status/progress**" and "**result_output**" which will then be outputted to pipeline. At the moment, the status/progress output from the script is being outputted to the pipeline with desired output string. How do I limit only desired output to pipe while printing both progress and desired output to the terminal.

Comment: Use `Write-Host` to write straight to the host application's screen buffer. Use `Write-Progress` to write to the progress stream (the host application, eg. powershell.exe, can then use those progress messages to show a progress bar)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Starting with PowerShell 5.0, `Write-Host` no longer writes straight to the screen buffer anymore. Instead it [writes to the _information_ stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.2#description), which may be redirected or captured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [Mathias's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), PowerShell has built-in cmdlets to interact with it's different streams, all described in [**about_Output_Streams**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2). The only stream which can be captured by default is the [Success stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2#success-stream) (Standard Output) and, most of them can be redirected to it however not relevant to the question. See [**about_Redirection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) for more info on this.

Here is a little example of what's explained above and what may give you an idea on how to approach your code.

```
function ReceiveFromPipeline {
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject)

    process {
        "Receiving [$InputObject] from pipeline"
    }
}

$result = 1..100 | ForEach-Object {
    # this is Standard Output,
    # will be received by ReceiveFromPipeline function
    $_

    # This goes to the Info Stream and will not be captured in `$result`
    # unless redirected.
    Write-Host "Writing [$_] to the Information Stream"

    # This goes to the Progress Stream, cannot be redirected!
    Write-Progress -Activity "[$_] goes to the Progress Stream"
    
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
} | ReceiveFromPipeline
```